# Не работает hover

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Элемент `.nav__link` не работает при наведении, возможно проблема связана с тем, как я описал `header`, хотя я удалил этот код и у меня тоже ничего не работало.

Но, если в браузере, при помощи панели разработчика добавить элементу `:hover`, то так всё работает.

Также ещё при наведении на какой либо элемент при помощи выбора элементов в браузере ***Ctrl+Shift+C***, то в браузере не видно другие элементы, кроме `body`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
/*
font-family: MgOpenModata;
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; 
*/

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
ul {
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

img {
  display: block;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/*************** 

HEADER

****************/

.header {
  height: 100vh;
  background: url(https://www.eldorado.org.br/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/landing-bg.jpg) no-repeat 0 50%;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
}

.header:after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  z-index: -2;
}

.header__inner {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
}


/*************** 

NAV

****************/

.main-nav {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding: 40px;
  flex: 1;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.nav__link {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 18px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 10px;
}

.nav__link:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.nav__link:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.nav__link:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header__inner">
      <div class="logo">
        <a class="logo__a">
          <div class="logo__border"></div>
          <img class="logo__img" src="assets/img/logo.png" alt="">
          <div class="logo__border__bottom"></div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <nav class="main-nav">
        <a href="https://vk.com/al_im.php" class="nav__link">Home</a>
        <a href="#" class="nav__link">About</a>
        <a href="#" class="nav__link">Portfolio</a>
        <a href="#" class="nav__link">Clients</a>
        <a href="#" class="nav__link">Team</a>
        <a href="#" class="nav__link">Services</a>
        <a href="#" class="nav__link">Blog</a>
        <a href="#" class="nav__link">Contact</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: в инспекторе выберите ваш `nav__link`, и нажмите на `:hov` в подменю `Elements`. из выпадающего списка выберите `:hover` и покажите стили, которые отобразятся в инспекторе (преложите это фото)

Comment: Уже ответ нашли

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Он не работает из-за отрицательного значения свойства `z-index: -1;`, у вас `body` перекрывает блок `header`. Присвойте ему значение больше 1.

[Подробная информация на сайте MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)

Comment: Как всё просто :D